# Best algorithm to hash a string

Tags: algorithm, md5, sha

I want to use algorithm to do hash to long string.

I need that to be unique, since I log changes, and don't want to keep the whole string (that may vary from 300 bytes to 1000 bytes).

I think of MD5 (maybe sha - I don't know), but does this algorithm "promise" that there won't be any repeating of algorithm (even one for astronomic chance - What is the chance?).

Is there any better algorithm especially for strings value (all the ascii values that are readable. mostly all the letters and all the number-digits, including '-' and '.')?

Thanks :)

Comment: A hash is by definition not unique. Your approach must still work if the algorithm hashes two different strings to the same value, albeit with a small chance. Does it?

Comment: If memory is indeed a problem (is it? have you measured it?) and yet you still want exact matching, hashes won't help you, a hash is by definition lossy. What you can try is a lossless compression algorithm like [LZO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Rabin-Karp Algorithm (RK)
[Here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=stringSearching) is the tutorial from topcoder
You can learn a lot about hashing  from [here](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx)